# Evaluating $\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos(nx)}{2+\cos(x)} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> What is a good place to start in order to evaluate $$\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos(nx)}{2+\cos(x)} dx?$$

I just want something to set me on the right tracks. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enought to notice that the integral is an even function $$\sf I=\frac12 \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\cos(nx)}{2+\cos x}dx=\frac12\Re\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{e^{inx}}{2+\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}}dx$$
Now substitute $\sf e^{ix}=z\Rightarrow dx=\frac{dz}{iz} ,|z|=1$
$$\sf \Rightarrow I=\frac12\Re \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{z^n}{2+\frac{z^2+1} 
 {2z}}\frac{dz}{iz}=\Re\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{z^n}{z^2+4z+1}\frac{dz}{i}$$
$$\sf z^2+4z+1=(z+2)^2-3\Rightarrow z_{1,2}=\pm \sqrt 3-2$$
But only the pole $\sf z_1=\sqrt3-2$ is found inside our countour thus:
$$\sf I=\Re\left(2\pi \lim_{z\to z_1} (z-z_1)\frac{z^n}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}\right)=2\pi \frac{z_1^n}{z_1-z_2}=\frac{(\sqrt 3-2)^n}{\sqrt 3}\pi$$
An alternative approach can be found [here](https://ysharificalc.wordpress.com/2018/09/09/limit-of-integrals-16/).

Comment: Thanks. However I don't have access to complex analysis in my curriculum. Do you know if it's possible to do it without it ?

Comment: What are your available tools?

Comment: I have the basics: Integration by part, substitution, as well as theorems on improper integral. I can write what you did up to I being a real part but no I cant use holomorphic functions or line integral so no residue theorem. I basically can't differentiate in C but as long as my variables are real it should be ok.

Comment: @AdrickMamode See here then: https://ysharificalc.wordpress.com/2018/09/09/limit-of-integrals-16/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look into it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $u=2 \pi -x$. Then
$$\int_0^\pi \cos(nx)/(2+\cos(x))dx= -\int_{2\ pi}^\pi \cos(nu)/(2+\cos(u))du= \int_\pi^{2 \pi} \cos(nx)/(2+\cos(x))dx$$

Now, 
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(nx)/(2+\cos(x))dx$$ is a standard complex analysis computation: You figure out the "right" function, such that, under the parametrisation  $z=\cos(x) + i \sin(x)$ you get 
$$\int_{|z|=1} F(z) dz =\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(nx)/(2+\cos(x))dx$$

Comment: Hi, I don't have access to complex analysis in my curriculum. Do you know if it's possible to do it without it ?